# Trouble getting cpplint to work on Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, continuous-integration, cpplint

Does anyone know how to install cppcheck on Jenkins? I installed the plugin through Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins but when I follow the instructions and included an "execute shell" build step, it fails.

```
cppcheck src
```

returns an log file like this:

```
cppcheck: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I tried looking at some online tutorials, but they didn't seem to help fix the problem. Should I use the CLI to install cppcheck on Jenkins, rather than the web UI? I don't think that will fix the issue, as it seems that cppcheck is not installed on the server.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *"The Cppcheck plug-in scans for Cppcheck report files in the build workspace"* so you need to install and invoke cppcheck yourself

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded it using `yes | sudo apt-get install cppcheck` and it works now!